# How to know what program needs which group to be executed without sudo

Tags: permissions, groups, installed-programs

In particular I want to create bridges dynamically, but without the need of running it with `sudo`. I think it's the group `netdev`.

But is there, and I'm sure there is, a general answer to the question: **How can I determine the group needed to run a program without typing `sudo` in front of the command**

Comment: This lloks like two questions. Run command without `sudo` (use /etc/sudoers.d) for group `netdev` and find which group (top) a command runs under! Which should it be?

Comment: I'm not sure that's really the right question: in the example you give, AFAIK it's not about permissions required to run the program, it's about the permissions required for the program to modify a device file

Comment: I think he means how do you know which group you should add to user so the user don't have to use sudo.

Comment: @AlvinLiang yes that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

First run the command (I wish you'd told us which) without `sudo`. Take note of the device(s) mentioned in the error message.

Use `ls -l`, followed by the device(s), e.g.

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ ls -l /dev/ttyS1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 65 Dec 13 08:34 /dev/ttyS1
```

This device allows `rw` access for the owner (`root`) and members of the `dialout` group.

To add yourself to the `dialout` group,

```
sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

To make use of your new `dialout` group membership, either log out and log in, or `newgrp dialout` to start a shell with that group membership.

Comment: I am looking for a general answer. But let's assume I use the command `brctl addbr`. I prefer using the command `usermod` to add a user to a existing group. So your solution basically is: `ls - l $(which brctl)` or something similar to get the group?

Comment: I don't think there's general answer. If document does not say anything and you don't guess, how do you know which device it will use?